# Jquery slider next button not render next image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have total 5 images, when I click on next it take last image. For example if user render first image then click on next then it not showing next image in sequence it showing last image. How to resolve this issue?

Note : With bottom dot it working fine but when I tried with next button (>) it not working. I really hard but not able to resolve this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

  var buttons = "<button class=\"slidebtn prev\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-left\"></i></button><button class=\"slidebtn next\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-right\"></i></button\>";

  var slidesl = $('.slideitem').length
  var d = "<li class=\"dot active-dot\">&bull;</li>";
  for (var i = 1; i < slidesl; i++) {
    d = d + "<li class=\"dot\">&bull;</li>";
  }
  var dots = "<ul class=\"slider-dots\">" + d + "</ul\>";

  $("#slideshow").append(dots).append(buttons);
  var interval = setInterval(slide, 10000);

  function intslide(func) {
    if (func == 'start') {
      interval = setInterval(slide, 10000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  function slide() {
    sact('next', 1, 1200);
  }

  function sact(a, ix, it) {
    var currentSlide = $('.current');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slideitem');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev('.slideitem');
    var reqSlide = $('.slideitem').eq(ix);

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();
    var reqDot = $('.dot').eq(ix);

    if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
      nextSlide = $('.slideitem').first();
    }

    if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
      prevDot = $('.dot').last();
      prevSlide = $('.slideitem').last();
    }

    if (a == 'next') {
      console.log('@@@@@ dta', nextSlide)
      var Slide = nextSlide;
      var Dot = nextDot;
    } else if (a == 'prev') {
      var Slide = prevSlide;
      var Dot = prevDot;
    } else {
      var Slide = reqSlide;
      var Dot = reqDot;
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(it).removeClass('current');
    Slide.fadeIn(it).addClass('current');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    Dot.addClass('active-dot');
  }

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    intslide('stop');
    sact('next', 0, 400);
    intslide('start');
  }); //next

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    intslide('stop');
    sact('prev', 0, 400);
    intslide('start');
  }); //prev

  $('.dot').on('click', function() {
    intslide('stop');
    var index = $(this).index();
    sact('dot', index, 400);
    intslide('start');
  }); //prev
  //slideshow
});
```

```css
@media all and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:569px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    7 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 93% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 87% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

#slideshow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 430px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow>div>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#slideshow:hover i,
#slideshow:hover .slider-dots {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slidebtn {
  z-index: 99;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slidebtn:active,
.slidedtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slidebtn i {
  color: #252525 !important;
  font-size: 31px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.slider-dots {
  opacity: 0.2;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 109%;
  bottom: 3%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #696969;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-600w-668593321.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/set-two-beautiful-blue-turquoise-600w-1856321857.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/floral-spring-natural-blue-background-600w-1857077830.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/green-grass-chamomile-flowers-nature-600w-247906417.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/lovely-sunny-purple-color-blurred-260nw-404849365.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pink-blurred-background-260nw-1274874394.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/raindrops-on-purple-surface-metal-260nw-235002136.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML you have the class **current** for each **slideitem** at the beginning. Remove this class from the second element till the end as first step:

```
$('.slideitem:gt(0)').removeClass('current');
```

In the next and prev functions you need to compute current index instead of passing 0:

```
var index  = $('.dot.active-dot').index();
```

That's all. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3fnp2g60/1/)

```js
$(function () {
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

  var buttons = "<button class=\"slidebtn prev\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-left\"></i></button><button class=\"slidebtn next\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-right\"></i></button\>";

  var slidesl = $('.slideitem').length
  var d = "<li class=\"dot active-dot\">&bull;</li>";
  for (var i = 1; i < slidesl; i++) {
      d = d+"<li class=\"dot\">&bull;</li>";
  }
  var dots = "<ul class=\"slider-dots\">" + d + "</ul\>";

  $("#slideshow").append(dots).append(buttons);
  var interval = setInterval(slide, 10000);

  function intslide(func) {
      if (func == 'start') {
          interval = setInterval(slide, 10000);
      } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }

  function slide() {
      sact('next', 1, 1200);
  }

  function sact(a, ix, it) {
      var currentSlide = $('.current');
      var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.slideitem');
      var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev('.slideitem');
      var reqSlide = $('.slideitem').eq(ix);

      var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
      var nextDot = currentDot.next();
      var prevDot = currentDot.prev();
      var reqDot = $('.dot').eq(ix);

      if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
          nextDot = $('.dot').first();
          nextSlide = $('.slideitem').first();
      }

      if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
          prevDot = $('.dot').last();
          prevSlide = $('.slideitem').last();
      }

      if (a == 'next') {
          console.log('@@@@@ dta',nextSlide)
          var Slide = nextSlide;
          var Dot = nextDot;
      }
      else if (a == 'prev') {
          var Slide = prevSlide;
          var Dot = prevDot;
      }
      else {
          var Slide = reqSlide;
          var Dot = reqDot;
      }

      currentSlide.fadeOut(it).removeClass('current');
      Slide.fadeIn(it).addClass('current');

      currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
      Dot.addClass('active-dot');
  }

  $('.next').on('click', function(){
      intslide('stop');
      var index  = $('.dot.active-dot').index();
      sact('next', index, 400);
      intslide('start');
  });//next

  $('.prev').on('click', function(){
      intslide('stop');
      var index  = $('.dot.active-dot').index();
      sact('prev', index, 400);
      intslide('start');
  });//prev

  $('.dot').on('click', function(){
      intslide('stop');
      var index  = $(this).index();
      sact('dot', index, 400);
      intslide('start');
  });//prev

  $('.slideitem:gt(0)').removeClass('current');

  //slideshow
});
```

```css
@media all and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:105px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top:72% !important
  }

  .slider-dots li {
    color :  #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:569px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:105px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top:72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color :  #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:105px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;7
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top:72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color :  #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:105px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top:93% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color :  #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important ;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:105px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top:87% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color :  #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}
#slideshow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:430px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

#slideshow > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow > div > img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:20px;
}

#slideshow:hover i, #slideshow:hover .slider-dots{
  opacity: 1;
}

.slidebtn {
  z-index:99;
  background:transparent;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;

}

.slidebtn:active,
.slidedtn:focus {
  outline:none;}

.slidebtn i {
  color: #252525 !important;
  font-size:31px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;

}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}


.slider-dots {
  opacity: 0.2;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:109%;
  bottom:3%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index:99;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;

}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #696969;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideitem current">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-600w-668593321.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideitem current">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/set-two-beautiful-blue-turquoise-600w-1856321857.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideitem current">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/floral-spring-natural-blue-background-600w-1857077830.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideitem current">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/green-grass-chamomile-flowers-nature-600w-247906417.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="slideitem current">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/lovely-sunny-purple-color-blurred-260nw-404849365.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideitem current">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pink-blurred-background-260nw-1274874394.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideitem current">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/raindrops-on-purple-surface-metal-260nw-235002136.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tried to repair your code, but I can't. Really, there is an error, when clicking on next button. I can suggest you my working code. New js code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var buttons = "<button class=\"slidebtn prev\"><</button><button class=\"slidebtn next\">></button\>";

var slidesl = $('.slideitem').length
var d = "<li class=\"dot active-dot\">&bull;</li>";
for (var i = 1; i < slidesl; i++) {
  d = d+"<li class=\"dot\">&bull;</li>";
}   
var dots = "<ul class=\"slider-dots\">" + d + "</ul\>";

$("#slideshow").append(dots).append(buttons);

var slideitem_count = $('.slideitem').length;

$(".slideitem").hide();
$(".slideitem:first-child").show();
var current_slide = 1;
$('.next').on('click', function(){
    current_slide++;
  if (current_slide == slideitem_count + 1)
    current_slide = 1;
  if (current_slide != 1)
    $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + (current_slide - 1) + ")").hide();
  else
    $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + (slideitem_count) + ")").hide();
  $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + current_slide + ")").show();
});//next

$('.prev').on('click', function(){
    current_slide--;
  if (current_slide == 0)
    current_slide = slideitem_count;
  if (current_slide != slideitem_count)
    $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + (current_slide + 1) + ")").hide();
  else
    $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + 1 + ")").hide();
  $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + current_slide + ")").show();          
});//prev

$('.dot').click(function(){
    var dot_index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + current_slide + ")").hide();
  $(".slideitem:nth-child(" + dot_index + ")").show();
  current_slide = dot_index;
});
//slideshow
});
```

Working sample - [js fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/u7jp01t4/48/)

Comment: perhaps put the full code IN the answer (not the linked fiddle) as a snippet

Comment: I don't change anything in other files. Linked fiddle isn't answer, it's something like example, presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

  var buttons = "<button class='slidebtn prev'><i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-left'></i></button><button class='slidebtn next'><i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></i></button\>";

  var dots = $("<ul>", {
    class: "slider-dots"
  }).appendTo("#slideshow");

  $('.slideitem').each(function(i, el) {
    dots.append("<li class='dot'>&bull;</li>");
  });
  $(".dot:first", dots).addClass("active-dot");

  $("#slideshow").append(buttons);
  var interval = setInterval(slide, 10000);

  function intslide(f) {
    if (f == 'start') {
      interval = setInterval(slide, 10000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  function slide() {
    if ($(".current").length) {
      sact($(".current").index() + 1, 1200);
    } else {
      sact(1, 1200);
    }
  }

  function jump(ix, it) {
    $(".current").fadeOut(it, function() {
      $(".current").removeClass("current");
      $(".active-dot").removeClass("active-dot");
    });
    $(".slideitem").eq(ix).fadeIn(it, function() {
      $(".slideitem").eq(ix).addClass("current");
      $(".dot").eq(ix).addClass("active-dot");
    })
  }

  function sact(ix, it) {
    if (ix > $(".slideitem").length - 1) {
      ix = 0;
    }
    if (ix < 0) {
      ix = $(".slideitem").length - 1;
    }
    jump(ix, it);
    intslide("start");
  }

  $('.slidebtn, .dot').on('click', function() {
    intslide('stop');
    var i = $(this).index();
    if ($(this).hasClass("next")) {
      i = $(".current").index() + 1;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("prev")) {
      i = $(".current").index() - 1;
    }
    sact(i, 400);
  });
});
```

```css
@media all and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:569px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    7 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 72% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 93% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slidebtn i {
    color: #252525 !important;
    font-size: 31px !important;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .slider-dots {
    top: 87% !important
  }
  .slider-dots li {
    color: #696969 !important;
  }
  .slider-dots li.active-dot {
    color: #252525 !important;
  }
}

#slideshow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 430px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow>div>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#slideshow:hover i,
#slideshow:hover .slider-dots {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slidebtn {
  z-index: 99;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slidebtn:active,
.slidedtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slidebtn i {
  color: #252525 !important;
  font-size: 31px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.slider-dots {
  opacity: 0.2;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 109%;
  bottom: 3%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #696969;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="slideitem current">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-600w-668593321.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/set-two-beautiful-blue-turquoise-600w-1856321857.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/floral-spring-natural-blue-background-600w-1857077830.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/green-grass-chamomile-flowers-nature-600w-247906417.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/lovely-sunny-purple-color-blurred-260nw-404849365.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pink-blurred-background-260nw-1274874394.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideitem">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/raindrops-on-purple-surface-metal-260nw-235002136.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was seeing a large Error in console. I could not really figure out what the error was but it was occurring directly after the initial "next" call.

As I looked over the code, it just felt like it was overly complex. In my opinion, I look as each of the `slideitem` as a part of the an array of Divs, and we can simply manage it in a similar manner. To move to next or prev, we just move our array index (+1 or -1) or jump to a new index.

This is the basis for my example. `jump()` just performs the fade to a new item, it does not care, you just give it the Index and Interval.

I adjusted sact() to do be concerned about the wrapping from end to beginning and vice versa. So now we can click on a dot and send it through or we Next or Prev and it all works.